# Add fields dynamically with alias

Tags: javascript, formvalidation.io

I am trying to add dynamically some fields to a form validated with fomavalidation.io v1.10.0 with validators using alias.

Here is the piece of code:

```
const $sp_param_delay_min = $('#sp_param_delay_min');
const param_delay_max = $('#sp_param_delay_max');

_fv.addField($sp_param_delay_min[0].name, {
  validators: {
    callback: {
      message: 'You must fill at least one of the two delay fields',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value !== '' || $sp_param_delay_max.val() !== '';

        _fv.updateFieldStatus(
          $sp_param_delay_max[0].name,
          is_valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid',
          'callback'
        );
        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    lessThanMax: {
      alias: 'callback',
      message: 'The delay min must be smaller than the delay max',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value === '' ||
          $sp_param_delay_max.val() === '' ||
          parseInt(input.value) < parseInt($sp_param_delay_max.val());

        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    integer: {
      message: 'The delay min must be an integer'
    },
    greaterThan: {
      min: 0,
      message: 'The delay min must be greater than 0',
      inclusive: false
    }
  }
});

_fv.addField($sp_param_delay_max[0].name, {
  validators: {
    callback: {
      message: 'You must fill at least one of the two delay fields',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value !== '' || $sp_param_delay_min.val() !== '';

        _fv.updateFieldStatus(
          $sp_param_delay_min[0].name,
          is_valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid',
          'callback'
        );
        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    moreThanMin: {
      alias: 'callback',
      message: 'The delay max must be greater than the delay min',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value === '' ||
          $sp_param_delay_min.val() === '' ||
          parseInt(input.value) > parseInt($sp_param_delay_min.val());

        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    integer: {
      message: 'The delay max must be an integer'
    },
    greaterThan: {
      min: 0,
      message: 'The delay max must be greater than 0',
      inclusive: false
    }
  }
});
```

The `Alias` plugin is registered when the `_fv` object is created:

```
const _fv = $modalForm.formValidation(
  {
    fields: {
      ...
    },
    plugins: {
      trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger({
        delay: {
          step_name: 0.5
        }
      }),
      bootstrap3: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap3(),
      icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
        valid: 'fas fa-check',
        invalid: 'fas fa-times',
        validating: 'fas fa-refresh'
      }),
      sequence: new FormValidation.plugins.Sequence({
        enabled: true,
      }),
      alias: new FormValidation.plugins.Alias()
    }
  }
).data('formValidation');
```

All the validators are working well except for the `lessThanMax` and `moreThanMin` ones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution.

I had basically to use the API function `registerPlugin()`.

So If I reedit the code above:

```
const $sp_param_delay_min = $('#sp_param_delay_min');
const param_delay_max = $('#sp_param_delay_max');

_fv.addField($sp_param_delay_min[0].name, {
  validators: {
    callback: {
      message: 'You must fill at least one of the two delay fields',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value !== '' || $sp_param_delay_max.val() !== '';

        _fv.updateFieldStatus(
          $sp_param_delay_max[0].name,
          is_valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid',
          'callback'
        );
        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    lessThanMax: {
      message: 'The delay min must be smaller than the delay max',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value === '' ||
          $sp_param_delay_max.val() === '' ||
          parseInt(input.value) < parseInt($sp_param_delay_max.val());

        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    integer: {
      message: 'The delay min must be an integer'
    },
    greaterThan: {
      min: 0,
      message: 'The delay min must be greater than 0',
      inclusive: false
    }
  }
});

_fv.addField($sp_param_delay_max[0].name, {
  validators: {
    callback: {
      message: 'You must fill at least one of the two delay fields',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value !== '' || $sp_param_delay_min.val() !== '';

        _fv.updateFieldStatus(
          $sp_param_delay_min[0].name,
          is_valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid',
          'callback'
        );
        return true;
      }
    },
    moreThanMin: {
      message: 'The delay max must be greater than the delay min',
      callback: (input) => {
        let is_valid =
          input.value === '' ||
          $sp_param_delay_min.val() === '' ||
          parseInt(input.value) > parseInt($sp_param_delay_min.val());

        return is_valid;
      }
    },
    integer: {
      message: 'The delay max must be an integer'
    },
    greaterThan: {
      min: 0,
      message: 'The delay max must be greater than 0',
      inclusive: false
    }
  }
});

_fv.registerPlugin(
  'Alias',
  new FormValidation.plugins.Alias({
    moreThanMin: 'callback',
    lessThanMax: 'callback'
  })
);
```

And remove the Alias plugin initialisation in the `_fv` instance:

```
const _fv = $modalForm.formValidation(
  {
    fields: {
      ...
    },
    plugins: {
      trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger({
        delay: {
          step_name: 0.5
        }
      }),
      bootstrap3: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap3(),
      icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
        valid: 'fas fa-check',
        invalid: 'fas fa-times',
        validating: 'fas fa-refresh'
      }),
      sequence: new FormValidation.plugins.Sequence({
        enabled: true,
      })
    }
  }
).data('formValidation');
```

It is now working :-)